# React Native function issue

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to learn how to make section header listview and follow tutorial from https://medium.com/@darylrowland/reactnative-listview-with-section-headers-99a6714282c3#.t5fj6dswg.I'm new at JS thing, so I'm stuck at a function and don't know why is it keep saying "Unexpected token at some line". I already try 4 different way to make function from many tutorial but still stuck can someone help me fix it?

```
function ubahArrayMahasiswaJadiMap() {
  var kategoriMahasiswa = {}; //buat map kosong
  mahasiswa.forEach(mhs){  //source problem here after mhs
    if (!kategoriMahasiswa[mhs.sex]){
      //buat masukan pada map
      kategoriMahasiswa[mhs.sex] = [];
    }

    kategoriMahasiswa[mhs.sex].push(mhs);
  }

  return kategoriMahasiswa;
}
```

I already try changing it to

```
mahasiswa.forEach(mhs){
.....}

mahasiswa.forEach((mhs)){
    .....}

mahasiswa.forEach(function(mhs)){
    .....}
```

the problem still exist.

here is my full source code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

var mahasiswa = [
  {name: "Budi", sex : "male"},
  {name: "Ayu", sex : "female"},
  {name: "Tika", sex : "female"},
  {name: "Dara", sex : "female"},
  {name: "Abdul", sex : "male"},
  {name: "Jabbar", sex : "male"}
];

function ubahArrayMahasiswaJadiMap() {
  var kategoriMahasiswa = {}; //buat map kosong
  mahasiswa.forEach(mhs){ <------------------------------------- problem before the bracket
    if (!kategoriMahasiswa[mhs.sex]){
      //buat masukan pada map
      kategoriMahasiswa[mhs.sex] = [];
    }

    kategoriMahasiswa[mhs.sex].push(mhs);
  }

  return kategoriMahasiswa;
}

export default class ListLagi extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native Oke Dong !
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ListLagi', () => ListLagi);
```

Comment: Which is the line that it refers to in the error ?

Comment: mahasiswa.forEach(mhs){  //source problem here after mhs @Ian

Comment: Shouldn't it be like mahasiswa.forEach(function(mhs){ ... } ) maybe ?

Comment: ok lemme try @Ian

Comment: it's not working :( @Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your forEach loop, and compare with this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Your syntax is wrong, your syntax should be something like:

```
mahasiswa.forEach((mhs) => {    
    // do this.
  });
```

Comment: I'm following tutorial, got some different syntax too on each tutorial. Ok I'll try this